# controlling the height change speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, height

I have the below javascript for a height change of a div.
However, I don't know how to adjust the speed when the div reveals. 
i know 500 is the speed when the height of the div changes to 
30px, but i don't know how to control the speed when it changes back to 100%. 
can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mydiv").click(function(){
var $this = $('#mydiv_2');
    $this.animate({height: $this.height() == 30 ? '100%' : 30}, 500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this.animate({height: $this.height() == 30 ? '100%' : 30}, 500);
```

The second property is your speed in milliseconds.

Comment: it only controls the speed when the height changes back to 30px.

Comment: how do you control the speed when it changes to 100%?

Comment: In fact, there is no way to set height in percent with "animate" function.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i'm trying to show a part of a div then reveal it to 100%. therefore overflow is hidden then animate it to 100% from 30px which is the part that viewers will see at first.

Comment: i think the fiddle works the other way around. it shows 100% at first then changes to 30px can you show fix this matter?

Comment: In my example 100% of height is less then 30px. I'll show it in div there http://jsfiddle.net/783Xn/2/

Comment: yes, but in my case 100% of height is more than 30px. I only show 30px in the beginning and show the rest on click, which is 500px.

Comment: That's not a problem http://jsfiddle.net/ZSbbK/2/ . Now it count 100% always, even if div content change.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
The second parameter of `animate()` controls the speed (larger is slower).

**EDIT:**
If you want different speeds when the div hide and reveals, try this:

```
if ($this.height() == 30) {
    $this.animate({height: '100%'}, 1200);
} else {
    $this.animate({height: 30}, 500);
}
```

Comment: i know 500 controls the speed when it reduces the height of the div. but i don't know how to control when the height changes to 100%

Answer (score 0):

use slow in animate like this

```
$this.animate({height: $this.height() == 30 ? '100%' : 30},'slow');
```

if you need even slower use time in milliseconds in place of slow

```
$this.animate({height: $this.height() == 30 ? '100%' : 30}, 1200);
```

this will slow it down for 1.2 seconds, adjust accordingly :)

also take a look at [Jquery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more options

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter on `animate()` is the duration in ms
`1000`ms equals `1`second.

see [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)